# Specify the callback parameter with JQuery.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

Is there any way to specify the value of the callback parameter when using JQuery's getJSON method?

For example:

```
$.getJSON('/content?callback=?', function(data) {});
```

Generates the following URL:

```
content?callback=jQuery15108431726952168015_1299633045933&_=1299633046552
```

The parameter here is generated randomly by the library.

I would like to specify my own callback parameter.

I would like to use the same callback parameter for every request so I can aggresively cache the response.

Comment: Are you looking to use JSONP where you specify the callback in the request URL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to be at least on jQuery 1.5 for this to work.

```
// The URL generated is "/content?callback=myCallback"
$.ajax({
  url: '/content?callback=?',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'myCallback',
  cache: true,
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All of jQuery's ajax convenience functions are just wrappers for $.ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

Why not create your own convenience wrapper?

```
function fetchJSON(url, data, callback) {
    return jQuery.get(url, data, callback, "json");
}
```